# Error -32700 on posting form data to jsponrpc endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, json-rpc

I am creating a billing form to send data to a jsonrpc endpoint. Though the server returns status code 200; i get this response {message: "Parse error. Invalid JSON was received by the server.", code: -32700,..}

```js
    $(document).on("submit", "#billing", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();        
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {new FormData(this)},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            console.log('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });        
});
```

```html
<form name="billing" id="billing" action="https://XX.XX.XX.XX/ghe/api2/call/jsonrpc2" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"/> <br/>
    Surname: <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" /> 
<br/>
    Email : <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/> 
<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I saw somewhere to use stringify and tried that also via:

```html
$("#submit").click(function()
{
 $("#billing").submit(function(e)
 {
  var postData = $(this).stringify();
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax(
  {
   url: $form.attr('action'),
   type: "POST",
   data : postData,
   success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
   {
    console.log("success");

   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
   {
    console.log("Failed");
   }
  });
 });
  
 $("#billing").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});
```

But i still get that same error response. What am i doing wrong? New to the use of APIs so my know how is kinda scattered now; would appreciate if can be pointed to a resource learning url best for APIs..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the payload that is being sent to the server to see what is causing the invalid Json-Rpc exception.

Your could `console.log(postData)`.
Or i'd suggest your browser debugger or [fiddler](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt4ev10-TWAhWB7SYKHSk-CsgQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Ffiddler&usg=AOvVaw1z5m3-3s7jUdTLvNJwRzLI).

Once you have captured the json that is being sent to the server you can drop it in a json linter [jsonLint.com](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiD5rnV1OTWAhXD6oMKHfAVD1sQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjsonlint.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1wm0AnA86fJrIoZRGRzp6P) and see what's causing your trouble.